# How to access an instance from one Kodein module in a different module?

Tags: android, kotlin, kodein

When using Kodein, if I have 2 modules and `module B` needs to use an instance from `module A`, is the best practice to import `module A` into `module B` or is there a better way to do it?

For example, I have a `networkingModule`:

```
val networkingModule = Kodein.Module("networking") {
    bind<Retrofit>() with singleton {
        Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.example.com/")
            .build()
    }
}
```

And `subscribersModule` needs the Retrofit instance from `networkingModule`:

```
val subscribersModule = Kodein.Module("subscribersModule") {
    import(networkingModule)
    bind<SubscribersService>() with singleton {
        instance<Retrofit>().create(SubscribersService::class.java)
    }
}
```

Is adding the `import(networkingModule)` in `subscribersModule` the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, if your modules are used in one project, you're not force to make them dependant.

Instead you can import them in a global container, like this:

```kotlin
val applicationContainer = Kodein {
    import(subscribersModule)
    import(networkingModule)
    // ...
}
```

Kodein-DI will solve the dependencies for you.